# Trigger LMD - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I would like to execute the trigger below in order for the error to be raised("You are not allowed to change the date"), that should be triggered when someone tries to change the date in the table, but I can't manage to find out how I can call the trigger. I did try SET DataValiditate = TO_DATE(DataValiditate, 'yyyy/mm/dd') + '2023/10/14';, but it doesn't work. Please could you help me? Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE ProduseAchizitionate (
 ID_Achizitii NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 CodProdus NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 Cantitate NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 DataValiditate DATE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_ProduseAchizitionate PRIMARY KEY(ID_Achizitii)
);


ALTER TABLE ProduseAchizitionate
ADD CONSTRAINT "include" FOREIGN KEY (ID_Achizitii) 
REFERENCES Achizitii(ID_Achizitii) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE ProduseAchizitionate
 ADD CONSTRAINT "cuprinde" FOREIGN KEY (CodProdus) 
 REFERENCES Medicament(CodProdus) ON DELETE CASCADE;
INSERT ALL
 INTO ProduseAchizitionate(ID_Achizitii, CodProdus, Cantitate, 
 DataValiditate) 
 VALUES(01,04,40,TO_DATE('2023/10/10','yyyy/mm/dd'))
SELECT * FROM dual;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER produseAchizitionate_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF DataValiditate ON ProduseAchizitionate
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.DataValiditate <> :OLD.DataValiditate) THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201,'Data expirarii produsului nu poate fi modificata!');
END IF;
END;
/

UPDATE ProduseAchizitionate
SET DataValiditate = TO_DATE(DataValiditate, 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Comment: " I can't manage to find out how I can modify the date." - what does that mean?  You need to post a [mcve] including the table definitions and sample data and better explanation

Comment: you still have  not explained what the problem is

Comment: still don't understand. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown, your `UPDATE` isn't changing the value of the date at all, so the trigger won't evaluate the error condition. Try replacing your `to_date` with `SYSDATE`, or `TO_DATE('2023/10/14', 'yyyy/mm/dd')`:

```
CREATE TABLE ProduseAchizitionate (
 ID_Achizitii NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 CodProdus NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 Cantitate NUMBER(9) NOT NULL,
 DataValiditate DATE NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT pk_ProduseAchizitionate PRIMARY KEY(ID_Achizitii)
);
   
INSERT ALL
 INTO ProduseAchizitionate(ID_Achizitii, CodProdus, Cantitate, 
 DataValiditate) 
 VALUES(01,04,40,TO_DATE('2023/10/10','yyyy/mm/dd'))
SELECT * FROM dual;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER produseAchizitionate_update
BEFORE UPDATE OF DataValiditate ON ProduseAchizitionate
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.DataValiditate <> :OLD.DataValiditate) THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201,'Data expirarii produsului nu poate fi modificata!');
END IF;
END;
/

UPDATE ProduseAchizitionate SET DataValiditate = SYSDATE;
```

Output:

```
Table PRODUSEACHIZITIONATE created.


1 row inserted.


Trigger PRODUSEACHIZITIONATE_UPDATE compiled


Error starting at line : 37 in command -
UPDATE ProduseAchizitionate SET DataValiditate = SYSDATE
Error report -
ORA-20201: Data expirarii produsului nu poate fi modificata!
ORA-06512: at "PETE.PRODUSEACHIZITIONATE_UPDATE", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PETE.PRODUSEACHIZITIONATE_UPDATE'
```

Comment: Thank you, @pmdba. I ran the script with SYSDATE, but I get the same thing as before: Trigger PRODUSEACHIZITIONATE_UPDATE compiled

0 rows updated.

Comment: Now the error appears. I dropped the trigger, refreshed the DB, I inserted again the data in table, and the update is taking place

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @pmdba. I am new at PL/SQL, so, it takes awhile to understand